# C: Programming a RPC Low Level Application: getting the IP address from client

Tags: c, client-server, rpc

I have programed a server-client application as a RPC (low-level).

This is my server function to validate my IP address (here, just the necessary information):

```
 int *checkip_1_svc(ip_adress *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
 {
     static int  result;
     struct sockaddr_in test_ip;

     result =1;

     return(&result);
 }
```

Now I want to print the IP address from the connected client.

I tried:

```
printf("Clientadress:%s", rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

This does not work. I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: 1)Maybe `rqstp` is a NULL pointer. 2) `rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr.s_addr` is probably *not a string*

Comment: 1) it is not a NULL-Pointer.. I tried it. 2.) I tried to cast it with (char*) but that does not work, too!

Comment: well, that leaves 2) : it is not a string.

Comment: do u know how to cast it or to copy it to a string ;-) ?

Comment: Look it up in the header file where `struct svc_req` is defined. It is probably a union of int and char[] of some kind.

Comment: with a integer it works... but its a strange number ...like 16777343...

Comment: Try printing it in hex, with an "%08x" format. (since your code is incomplete and incomprehensive, I can't help you any further)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s_addr` most propably is an unsigned 32bit integer, so you might use `%u` but `%s`:

```
printf("client address: %u", rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

To have it printed in the `a.b.c.d` notation you might use:

```
#define SPLIT_S_ADDR_INTO_BYTES( \
    s_addr) \
    ((s_addr) >> 24) & 0xFF, \
    ((s_addr) >> 16) & 0xFF, \
    ((s_addr) >>  8) & 0xFF, \
    ((s_addr)      ) & 0xFF

...

printf(
  "client address: %hu.%hu.%hu.%hu", 
  SPLIT_S_ADDR_INTO_BYTES(ntohl(rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr.s_addr)));

...
```

For details on `ntohl()` please see `man ntohl()`.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as:

```
printf("Clientadress:%s", inet_ntoa(rqstp->rq_xprt->xp_raddr.sin_addr.s_addr));
```